# how does the structure dereference operator work?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, operators

I am a Java programmer trying to teach myself C++.

I would like to understand how the structure dereference operator works.  Specifically, what does the following line of code do in explicit terms?

```
    if (elements[i]->test(arga, argb)) {}
```

test(arga,argb) is a Boolean function in the same class, and elements is a vector of instances of the element class.  Here is the code that immediately surrounds the line above, about which I am interested:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < elements.size(); ++i) {
    T arga = INFINITY, argb = INFINITY;
    //using namespace std;
    //std::cout >> elements[i] >> std::endl;
    //std::cout >> test(arga, argb) >> std::endl;
    if (elements[i]->test(arga, argb)) {
        //some code
    }
}
```

It seems that the if line is testing to see whether or not the boolean returned by test(arga,argb) is part of the given instance of the elements class.  But when I try to expose the underlying values of elements[i] or test(arga,argb) with the cout lines above, the compiler throws errors until I comment those lines out.

In Java, I would be able to fiddle around with this until I found values of each that correspond with each other, and then I would understand the line of code.  How can I figure out what this line of code does in C++? I would be interested to see some references online if they are available.

Comment: Could you show the declaration of `elements`?

Comment: To help you understand: in C++ we distinguish `->` and `.` because they don't operate on the same things (pointer vs plain object and/or reference). But to relate you with your Java experience, you can *mostly* translate `->` to `.` ie. `elements[i].test(arga, argb)`. But keep in mind that C++ makes a difference between value and reference, while in Java pretty much everything is a reference.

Comment: @syam is right, but in C++ you can also define de-reference operators for user defined types. So in order to understand what you are actually asking, it is necessary to know what `elememts` is, and what type it holds, if it holds anything other than pointers.

Comment: Thank you each for your help.  I will log on and explore this later when I have time to deeply research and consider what it is that you each are saying.  In the meantime, +1 to everyone who tried to help so far.

Comment: @CodeMed: Again, where is the declaration of `elements`? In C++ there's no meaningful way to answer your question without knowing what `elements` is.

Comment: @AndreyT I will dig into this more deeply on Monday, so that I can provide more meaningful interaction.  It has been a long weekend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since numerous respondents told me that I need to provide the code before they can answer, I looked deeper in the code, and re-wrote something which tells me that the line:

```
if (elements[i]->test(arga, argb)) {}
```

is a test to see whether or not the boolean member function of elements[i] is true.

The c++ program that I wrote to identify the meaning of -> in this context is:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Bone
{
public:
    std::string myName;
    int mySize;
    Bone(const std::string &name, const int &size) : myName(name), mySize(size)
    {}
    bool isBigger(const int &testSize) const
    {
        if (testSize > mySize) return false;
        else return true;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::vector<Bone<float> *> bones;
    // name, location, size
    bones.push_back(new Bone<float>("femur", 10));
    bones.push_back(new Bone<float>("ulna", 4));
    bones.push_back(new Bone<float>("maxilla", 3));

    int testSize = 6;
    // test each bone to see if it is bigger than testSize
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < bones.size(); ++i) {
        if (bones[i]->isBigger(testSize)) {
            std::cout << bones[i]->myName; std::cout << " is bigger than testSize! " << std::endl;
        }
    }

    while (!bones.empty()) {
        Bone<float> *thisBone = bones.back();
        bones.pop_back();
        delete thisBone;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you to everyone who led me to figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

```
elements[i]->test (arga, argb)
```

---

If we break down the statement, reading from *left-to-right*, we will end up with the below:

1. access the `i`th element in an array (or *array-like*) entity named `elements`
2. the element accessed (`elements[i]`) is a pointer to an object
3. call the *member-function* named `test` on `elements[i]` and pass it two arguments; `arga` and `argb`

---

if we disregard the fact that you wrote `std::cout >>` instead of `std::cout <<` (the latter is the correct form), we end up with two reasons for your described errors:

1. your compiler complains about `std::cout << element[i]` because no suitable overload is found to handle an entity of the type of `element[i]` and an `std::ostream&` (which is the underlying type of `std::cout`).
2. your compiler complains about `std::cout << test (arga, argb)` because there is no function in scope named `test` that takes two arguments corresponding to `arga, argv`. `test`, in your snippet, is a *member-function* that belongs to an entity, it's not callable by its own.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to C++.

First, the syntax for output is:

```
cout<<
instead of
cout>>
```

You are right in guessing that test is a function that returns boolean.Here elements[i] is a pointer pointing to a struct element which has this test function.

To learn C++, you can use [these articles](https://docs.google.com/document/d/17yP-GkiiL1kuKJPQI7OQSEWhrE_rO_bWcI2nExBgXfU/edit) that I wrote.